# How do i prove whether $P[E|F] ≥ P[G|F]$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $E, F$, and $G$ be three events. If $P[E|F] ≥ P[G|F]$, is it sufficient to conclude that
$P[E] ≥ P[G]$? What additional relationship needs to be known between $P[E|F_c]$ and
$P[G|F_c]$?

For the first question, I have tried to expand the equation using conditional probability formula but yields no result. Then i add a condition that they are mutually independent such that their intersection is equal to their product and proven the inequality

My question is that can it be proven without the mutually independent condition and can i use the same condition and method to prove the second question that is: probability of $E$ given $F^\complement$ is greater than equal to probability of $G$ given $F^\complement$?

[image: My attempt]

Comment: Think about it like this. Suppose you randomly select a person from the entire world. Let $E$ be the event the person is from the United States, $G$ the event the person is from China, and $F$ the event the person used to be a president of the United States. What can you say about $P(E|F)$ and $P(G|F)$? What about $P(E)$ and $P(G)$?

Comment: that P(E|F)  would be greater than P(G|F)  but P(E) would be less than P(G)?

Comment: Exactly. In fact, $P(G|F)=0$.

Comment: and so what is the additional relationship do I need to know to prove the second question?

Comment: So you're wondering when $P(E|F)\geq P(G|F)$ implies $P(E|F^c)\geq P(G|F^c)$?

Comment: No, whether P(E|Fc)≥P(G|Fc) implies that P[E] > P[G]

Comment: You could redefine the event $F$ in my example to be that the randomly selected person never was a president of the United States to see that this isn't true.

Comment: Hmmm okay2 thank u very much

Comment: @MatthewPilling you have an example without probabilities of 0 or 1?